# Can't broadcast ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED for a system app

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I developed an app and copied it to `/system/priv-app` in a rooted Android device to make my app a system app and It works But still when I try to run below code I get an exception that only system can broadcast this.

```
val newIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
newIntent.putExtra("state", false)
sendBroadcast(newIntent)
```

My Android version is `7.1.1` is there any workaround for this? I want to broadcast this after changing the airplane mode with this code

```
Settings.System.putInt(contentResolver, Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your app has to be signed by the platform key and also assigned the `system` user (specified in the manifest.) Placing the app in `/system/priv-app` does not grant it any special functionality.